# How can I run a robocorp or robotframework file (.robot) on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, bots, robotframework, rpa

I have been testing my robocorp codes via Robocorp Lab (IDE), but I want to give it a try in a Raspberry Pi to make some tests, do you know how to do such thing?

I cant install Robocorp Lab or rcc in Raspberry Pi, they are not available, is there any option to run it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea about robocorp lab IDE. But to run .robot file on raspberry pi you only need to install [robot framework](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#installation-instructions).
It depends on what you already have on your raspberry,in case you don't have pip or python already installed, this should work:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip install robotframework
```

then just run your file with

```
robot your_file.robot
```